# Adding the same image every time a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, imageview

I making a drawing pad for teachers, i want to include geometrical shapes in it, there is a button on click of which a shape is displayed.
What i am doing now is i created an image view already and set its visibility to gone, on button i am making it visible.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivReact"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        />
```

i want the previous image to be there, when a button is clicked the same image should be added twice in the layout and if the button clicked again it should be added again and go on.
is it possible to do that?

Comment: create array of your images and replace image in imageview with your button click

Comment: it will replace the image, but i want to add it again..

Comment: do you want to images in list?

Comment: no not in list.. i have a layout in which i am adding the image like an image of circle.. i want to add more circles in the same layout when a button is clicked..

Comment: overlapped images is that you wanted to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Use this code inside onclick 

ImageView imageview = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
     RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout
     .LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     // Add image path from drawable folder.
     imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo_new_image);
     imageview.setLayoutParams(params); 
     relativelayout.addView(imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update image programmatically when button is clicked:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

EDIT:

If you have ImageViews in LinearLayout, you can simply create new and add to layout:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout_name, null);
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: No, i want the previous image  to be there, when a button is clicked the same image should be added twice in the layout and if the button clicked again it should be added thrice and go on..

Comment: @ManojKumar then just add views at runtime when clicked.

Comment: @ManojKumar I have udpated my answer

Answer (score 1):

create a recycler view and put a image view there. Create a arraylist. Onclick add same image to the arraylist and apply adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().